# angular-summernote not working ng-blur()

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I am using `angular-summernote`. When I am using `ng-blur()` and `ng-focus()` with `angular-summernote` then it will not call my function.

```
<summernote ng-model="test.desc" ng-blur="markChange();" 
     config="summerNoteOpts"></summernote>
```

If I use `ng-change()` with `angular-summernote` then it will work.

```
<summernote ng-model="test.desc" ng-change="markChange();" 
     config="summerNoteOpts"></summernote>
```

I am new to `angular-summernote`. Please help me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/16xL9np9/

Comment: it's working.thanks

Comment: Nope.  welcome..